# NodeJS is throwing an error on a route starting with a percent sign

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a server written NodeJS, where the backend setup is something like this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('main page here')
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.send('404 dude')
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
});
```

When I hit my server at `/%`, I get this stack trace:

```
Error: Bad Request
    at SendStream.error (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:239:16)
    at SendStream.pipe (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:411:32)
    at serveStatic (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:107:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:13)
    at /Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:237:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:12)
    at /Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:228:12
    at Function.match_layer (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:295:3)
    at next (/Users/danielchao/code/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:10)
```

Why is my static assets handler erroring out on this? Ideally this should really be handled as a 404.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the escape character in a url.

If you want a literal `%` in your url then use this: `%25`

Comment: I'm not concerned about how I reference a correct URL--my concern is when somebody hits my server at URL `/%`, my static handler throws an exception, when it shouldn't be. It should pass onto the next step in my middleware

Comment: Got it.  Yeah, the static asset handler shouldn't be killing over like that.  What version of Express are you using?

Comment: This is on the latest release, so express 4.10.1. Not sure if this matters, but I'm on node version 0.10.24

Comment: I did more digging, and the root culprit is here. https://github.com/tj/send/blob/master/index.js#L411

The send module handles bad URI's as errors, which is fine, and the serve-static module just passes this error on through, so unless caught somewhere else, it just passes through the entire middleware stack.

serve-static really should accept an option to ignore bad URI's, I think, but this is an architecture question. My intermediate solution to fix this is to add this to my middleware stack:

`app.use(function(err, req, res, next){ err.status === 400 ? res.render('404') : next(err) });`